# Agrupar colunas no gráfico de barras do R

Tags: r

Preciso gerar um gráfico de barras com os seguintes dados:

```
structure(c(38792L, 1227L, 23220L, 4177L, 893L, 331L), .Dim = 6L, .Dimnames = structure(list(c("Canvas para Android", "Canvas para iOS", "Chrome ", "Firefox ", "Navegador não reconhecido", "Safari ")), .Names = ""), class = "table")
```

Preciso agrupar as barras de "Canvas para Android" e "Canvas para iOS", logo abaixo delas devo colocar um rótulo "Dispositivo Mobile" e também precisarei agrupar as demais barras adicionando um logo "Computador".

Fiz o gráfico da seguinte forma:

```
AgUsuPlot<- barplot(table(AgenteDoUsuario[,1]),
        main = "Distribuição de Frequência do Agente do Usuário",
        ylim = c(0,45000),
        xlab="Agente do Usuário",
        col = c("palegreen", "green", "orange", "darkred", "red", "darkblue"),
        ylab="Exibições de Páginas",
        legend = rownames(table(AgenteDoUsuario[,1])),
        cex.axis = 0.6,
        cex.names = 0.6,
        space = 0.5,
        las=1
)
text(x=AgUsuPlot, y=table(AgenteDoUsuario[,1]), label=table(AgenteDoUsuario[,1]), pos = 3, xpd=NA)
```

Gostaria de saber como posso diminuir a legenda, pois ela está ficando em cima de uma das barras.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vamos por partes,

a) Para agrupar as barras, inclua o vetor de espaços `space = c(0.5, 0, .5, 0, 0, 0)` no código de construção do seu gráfico de barras. Essa opção especifica o espaço antes de cada barra, e você pode colocar uma única opção ou um espaçamento para cada barra do gráfico.

b) Para diminuir a legenda, crie a mesma com o comando `legend` e modifique a opção `cex` - só não esqueça de retirar a opção da legenda dentro do código do gráfico

```
legend("topright", legend = names(AgenteDoUsuario), cex = 0.6,
   fill = c("palegreen", "green", "orange", "darkred", "red", "darkblue"))
```

c) Para colocar os rótulos, eu utilizei o comando `mtext` com as palavras específicas. Além disso, para melhor posicionamento, eu retirei o nome de cada coluna do gráfico, com a opção `names.arg = NA` e os coloquei também utilizando o comando `mtext`.

O código final ficou

```
AgenteDoUsuario <- structure(c(38792L, 1227L, 23220L, 4177L, 893L, 331L), .Dim = 6L, .Dimnames = structure(list(  c("Canvas para Android", "Canvas para iOS", "Chrome ", "Firefox ", "Navegador não reconhecido", "Safari ")), .Names = ""), class = "table")

AgUsuPlot<- barplot(AgenteDoUsuario,
                    main = "Distribuição de Frequência do Agente do Usuário",
                    names.arg = NA, ylim = c(0,45000), xlab = "Agente do Usuário",
                    col = c("palegreen", "green", "orange", "darkred", "red", "darkblue"),
                    ylab = "Exibições de Páginas", cex.axis = 0.6,
                    cex.names = 0.6, space = c(0.5, 0, .5, 0, 0, 0),
                    las = 1
)
text(x = AgUsuPlot, y = AgenteDoUsuario, label = AgenteDoUsuario, pos = 3, xpd= NA)
mtext(names(AgenteDoUsuario), side = 1, at = c(1,2,3.5,4.5,5.5,6.5), cex = 0.6)
mtext(c("Dispositivo Mobile", "Computador"), side = 1, at = c(1.5, 5), line = 1)
legend("topright", legend = names(AgenteDoUsuario), cex = 0.6,
   fill = c("palegreen", "green", "orange", "darkred", "red", "darkblue"))
```

Comment: Perfeito Rafael! Todos os comandos funcionaram lindamente!

Comment: Obrigado demais!

O primeiro comando `mtext` estava mostrando os antigos rótulos, fiz pequenas alterações no seu código e o gráfico ficou do jeito que eu queria! Muito obrigado Rafael! Está salvando o meu TCC rsrs.

Comment: Que bom que deu certo. Considere [votar e aceitar](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/como-e-por-que-aceitar-uma-resposta) a minha resposta se ela resolveu o seu problema